# Timber log is not printing in debug console or Logcat

Tags: timber-android

```
Log.i("Test", "Hello, Log")
Timber.i("Hello, Timber")
```

I can see the Log.i log in Debug console and Logcat, I don't see the Timber log in anywhere.

> I/Test: Hello, Log

I'm building in stagingDebug mode. (I have 4 options, production debug and release and staging debug and release)

What I'm missing?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Make sure that you have initialised `Timber` in `Application` class. Following code might help :-

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        // This will initialise Timber
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if the `new` keyword is necessary, this worked for me: `Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())`

Comment: @claytonjwong that's Java code, new not required for Kotlin

Comment: In java you need to add new.But in ktx, it is to requires

Answer (score 15):

If you're initializing Timber like this:

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
    Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
}
```

Be sure, that you're imported BuildConfig from your app package, and not something like BuildConfig's from 3rd party libraries like this: `import org.koin.android.BuildConfig`. I strugled with this a few times.

Answer (score 14):

initialization Timber in Kotlin

```
class ExampleApplication : Application(){

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        // init timber
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
        }
    }
}
```

and don't forget write `android:name` of Application in Manifest.xml:

```
<application
        android:name=".ExampleApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.PostMakerMassive">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
```

Answer (score 5):

In my case, I imported the incorrect BuildConfig. You can check if that is the issue with yours as well.

Answer (score 1):

Try to add `tag` in Timber. It should be set (automatically) based on the information in the Manifest, but it does not always happen (e.g. for custom devices with custom OS)

So first of all plant it:

```
// Java
Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());

// Kotlin
Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
```

and next set tag:

```
// custom tag
Timber.tag("your custom tag");

// or
Timber.tag("trolololololo");

// or something (more serious) from strings:
Timber.tag(getString(R.string.app_name))
```